# How to test a custom directive from another module in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a UI library that we import into our app. In the UI library is a custom directive, `toggle`, that we use for opening and closing a modal. When I run unit tests, I get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: toggle

      (found in <Identity>)
```

In my `Identity` component, I'm using a component from the UI library, `checkbox`, that incorporates this directive:

```html
<checkbox
      :value="rememberMe"
      :label="$t('identity.rememberMeHeading')"
      name="rememberMe"
      data-test="remember-me"
      @input="toggleRememberMe()">
  <span slot="subtext"> {{ $t('identity.rememberMeSubheading') }}
    <a v-toggle:a-modal="'learn-more-modal'"
       @click.prevent="() => {}">{{ $t('identity.learnMore') }}</a>
  </span>
</checkbox>
```

How do I fix this error in my `Identity.spec.js`? After my imports, I have:

```
const localVue = createLocalVue()

localVue.use(Vuex)
localVue.use('toggle')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In `@vue/test-utils` 1.x, the second parameter of `shallowMount` and `mount` accepts a `directives` option that defines directives to use in the component. In 2.x, the option is [`global.directives`](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#global-directives). You could use this option to declare the `v-toggle` directive:

```js
shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  // @vue/test-utils @1.x
  directives: {
    toggle() { /* stub */ }
  },

  // @vue/test-utils @2.x
  global: {
    directives: {
      toggle() { /* stub */ }
    }
  }
})
```

For example, to ensure the directive is used in a component:

```js
const toggle = jest.fn()

shallowMount(MyComponent, {
  // @vue/test-utils @1.x
  directives: {
    toggle
  },

  // @vue/test-utils @2.x
  global: {
    directives: {
      toggle
    }
  }
})

expect(toggle).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

Comment: I can't find directives options on the docs https://v1.test-utils.vuejs.org/api/options.html . Can you refer me the docs? because I can't seems to make it work on @vue/test-utils@1.x.x